# executables on external hard drive detect as viruses

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, virus, anti-virus

I've been avoiding this issue for quite some time, but I feel like this is a good time to ask about it.

I have an external hard drive loaded up with most of my important and large files. for a few years, *some* of the computers that I have plugged it into have detected pretty much every .exe file it gets to as being a threat.

I'm honestly doubtful about some of this, because a lot of the files are downloaded from completely reputable sources. one time, I even downloaded Firefox Setup from Mozilla onto the drive, and plugged it into one of the computers it had issues with and the just-downloaded file was considered infected.

I'm getting tired of this and I'm starting to wonder if there's any way I can fix it. the drive is a *Western Digital Elements SE 1TB* drive formatted to *FAT32* (sucks, I know), and antiviruses I've experienced this with so far are *McAfee* and *Norton*, though I don't use either.

Comment: What type of "virus"? Any names?

Comment: @canha I completely forget! I can do some AV tests if it would help.

Comment: To analyse the issue I need the signatures that the Antivirus detected on the drive. They should be stated under "threat name" or something similar in the antivirus reports.

Comment: @Temikus I commented my results on the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I used to have this issue, I was **SO** annoyed with it. Anyway, your solution is to upgrade norton. Right-click on the norton icon and click "Check for updates". Install the newest update and your key should work with the upgrade. If it doesn't, I believe there's a free 60 day trial, after which you can either buy a new key or do the *ahem* other method of using the BOX! Norton trial reset. I'm not endorsing this, I'm just showing you your other options.

I've never used McAfee, so I wouldn't know about that. But what I said earlier is (to my knowledge) the only way around this, I've even asked on the Norton forums and an administrator told me that there wasn't anything built-in to Norton to allow it (because it's a medium level alert and you can only disable the low level one).

As far as I'm concerned, there's no hard-drive that avoids anti-viruses. This will most likely never be made, as it could be a very big workaround for being detected by anti-virus programs.

Comment: I've had good luck using [Microsoft Security Essentials - Free Antivirus for Windows](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/products/security-essentials) with its real-time protection turned on. Updates itself and doesn't seen to slow my system down like most of the other AV programs I tried did.

Comment: the issue is that it's not my computer that is doing this to me. it's an issue that I can't solve by touching the antivirus. @martineau Security Essentials has been good to me on other computers in my house but I haven't plugged my hard drive into those computers (playing it safe)

Comment: @parashep: Well, I think you need to be brave and plug it into one that has some kind of AV installed and scan the drive.

Comment: @martineau you may be right... I'll do some tests in a VM

Comment: Microsoft Security essentials doesn't slow down the system because it has no I/O filters whatsoever. It defends only against the most common threats and can't be considered a real endpoint security solution. I've seen way too many infected machines with MSE giving it a green status.

Comment: I did some tests with McAfee. each file it detected was W32/Mkar. in the time I let it search my drive it detected a few files which I downloaded straight to the drive for testing, plus a few more including Microsoft's Windows 7 USB tool. I'm fairly sure they were all setup files…

Comment: Try formatting it (back it all up first), then scanning it. If it comes up with nothing, put everything except the file it called a virus, back on, and scan it. Then, try re-downloading the "virus" files and putting the newly downloaded ones on your hard drive.

Comment: @chipperyman573 I'd have to get another hard drive to back this up because I can't fit it's data anywhere.